# React native update state and then use it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array in state, like initial state. What I want is to update this array on button press and then set updated array to the state. When button pressed again I want to update array that should be set after first button press but instead I one more time update initial array. I don't understand why `setCategoriesArray` doesn't set to the state updated on the first button press array, in another words why every time I update initial state though I have `setCategoriesArray(categoriesArray)` in the end of every condition.
Here is my code, help me please figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
    let [selected, setSelected] = useState(true);
    let [categoriesArray, setCategoriesArray] = useState(['mountains', 'ponds', 'beach', 'architecture', 'forest', 'abandoned', 'caves', 'careers', 'waterfall']);
    const buttonPress = () => {
            if (categoriesArray.includes(id)) {
                const index = categoriesArray.indexOf(id)
                categoriesArray.splice(index, 1)
                console.log('deleted', categoriesArray)
                setCategoriesArray(categoriesArray)
            } else {
                categoriesArray.push(id)
                console.log('newPushed', categoriesArray)
                setCategoriesArray(categoriesArray)
            }
            setSelected((prev) => !prev)
            sendDataToParent()
            console.log('resultArray', categoriesArray)
        }
    return <BorderlessTap onPress={() => buttonPress()} />
```

Comment: I don't remember the syntax for the setState hooks, but you could try `setSelected(!selected)` instead of trying to use `prev`. Otherwise, you're making the cardinal sin of state management. You're trying to modify the state directly with `categoriesArray.splice(index, 1)`. In general you should create a new array with the values of the old array and set that into state. `newCategoryArray = [...categoriesArray]`. And then do your splicing and such and `setCategoriesArray(newCategoryArray)`.

Comment: Also, because setState is async, when you console.log it you have no guarantee that it will be the updated state. In fact, it is more likely that it won't print the updated state.